# jQuery AJAX process not working (Updating div with JSON results)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to fetch some results from a database, then convert them to JSON and display the results in a div that is updated through AJAX and triggered by the Go! (form submit) button.

The code is not working, and I don't know why. I already checked my database connection, with other simple examples, and I am able to connect and even fetch results from the same database, but whenever I try to use it with AJAX/jQuery it does not work.

NOTE: Whenever I try to see the JSON object in the console, I get nothing but this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier index.php:20

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        Username:
        <input type="text" name="username" id="usrnfield"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Go!" id="subForm">
    </form>
    <div id="result">
        <p>Here are the usernames:</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#subForm").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST"                                      
                url: 'fetchuser.php',                          
                data: "",                        
                dataType: 'json',     
                success: function(data)
                {
                    var id = data[0];
                    var username = data[1];
                    var firstname = data[2];
                    var lastname = data[3];
                    var email = data[4];

                    $("#result").html("
                        <b>id: </b>"+id+"<br>
                        <b>Username: </b>"+username+"<br>
                        <b>First Name: </b>"+firstname+"<br>
                        <b>Last Name: </b>"+lastname+"<br>
                        <b>Email: </b>"+email+"<br>
                    "); 
                } 
            });
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

fetchuser.php:

```
<?php    
  $dbhost = "localhost";    
  $dbname = "database";    
  $dbuser = "root";    
  $dbpass = "root";    

  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
  $rows = array();

  if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM userlist WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($_POST['username']));
    $rows = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    echo json_encode($rows);
  }
?>
```

Comment: If you're using Firefox, install Firebug. If you're using Chrome, open the Developer Tools. Set a breakpoint in the .success callback and see what you're getting back from the AJAX call.

Comment: I see 1 syntax error, 1 logical error and 1 don't know the api error.

Comment: @PaulTomblin I am sorry for my noobness, but how do I do that?

Comment: @Musa Could you be more explicit? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier index.php:20` is for a missing trailing comma in the line 19

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST" // <-- Missing comma                                      
  url: 'fetchuser.php',
```

I've made some serious changes at your code, but is all commented... Some things are not 100% optimized for the sake of simplicity.

First, you can try the return value from the url (`localhost/site/fetchuser.php?username=Test`) with this approach.

In your php there was some errors:

```
<?php    
  $dbhost = "localhost";    
  $dbname = "database";    
  $dbuser = "root";    
  $dbpass = "root";    

  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
  // We use GET because $.getJSON uses GET =P
  if(isset($_GET['username'])) {
    // You have used the query function with execute, this is not correct
    // You need prepare with execute
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM userlist WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($_GET['username']));
    // FETCH_ASSOC would return the fields indexed by the field name.
    // In your success/done function you are using numbers index.
    // So, you need FETCH_OBJ
    // http://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-description
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
    echo json_encode($rows);
  } else {
    // This is not a json response, so it will trigger
    // the fail function in $.getJSON
    echo "Error";
  }
?>
```

---

In your HTML we make easy to jQuery interacts

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      /* Add a hide class to the #result */
      .hide {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!--
      In this case is better to listen to the submit
      event of the form, so we move the id subForm from the button
      to the form
    -->
    <form id="subForm">
        <!-- A label must be a <label> -->
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="usrnfield"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Go!">
    </form>
    <!-- div#result.hide -->
    <!-- The markup here is full, whit the fillable element identificated -->
    <div id="result" class="hide">
      <b>id: </b><span class="id"></span><br>
      <b>Username: </b><span class="username"></span><br>
      <b>First Name: </b><span class="firstname"></span><br>
      <b>Last Name: </b><span class="lastname"></span><br>
      <b>Email: </b><span class="email"></span><br>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        // Listen to the onSubmit event
        $('#subForm').on('submit', function(event) {
          // Avoid actual form submiting
          event.preventDefault();
          // Get the result element
          result = $('#result');
          // Delete the contents
          result.find('span').text('');
          // Hide the div
          result.hide();
          // We need the input#usrnfield value
          usrnfield = $('#usrnfield').val().trim();
          // And if the form is submited empty
          if (!usrnfield.length) {
            alert('Empty form');
          };
          // If we need to get JSON, then we use $.getJSON
          $.getJSON('fetchuser.php', {username: usrnfield})
            .done(function(data) {
              // We get the results to the console for testing
              console.log(data);
              // If there is no results
              if (!data.length) {
                alert('No results');
              };
              // We fill the html
              result.find('.id').text(data.id);
              result.find('.username').text(data.username);
              result.find('.firstname').text(data.firstname);
              result.find('.lastname').text(data.lastname);
              result.find('.email').text(data.email);
              // Then we show it up
              result.fadeIn();
            })
            .fail(function(){
              // If fails
              alert('No results');
            });
        });
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Respect... for you! Thanks a lot! you solved my problem. Just one thing, I had to debug the code a little because you misspelled "fetch" in the stmt->fetchALL part, but other than that, flawless correction and a very nice alternative for what I was trying to do!

Comment: Actually I found out that whenever the div gets the .hide class removed so it can show up all the results that are brought back from the DB I get the following output:

id: 2,test,Test,Lastname,test@page.com
Username: 
First Name: 
Last Name: 
Email:

Comment: =P Fetch, fetch, fetch... I've written that word a thousand times... And yep, I see your problem... Use FETCH_OBJ and then reference the db field name in the javascript. See my edited anwser

Comment: You'll have to match the data.* part in the javascript, also use the Developer Tools, they are your friend, press F12 in your keyboard. There (In the Console section/tab) you'll see the console.log output